# Mac Catalyst, unable to create a Safari Extension

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension, mac-catalyst

I've started a new iOS project enabling the option to deploy the same app in macOS (Catalyst). But when I try to create a Safari Extension in macOS, I get the following error

**'Safari Extension.appex' is a Safari extension, which is not available when building for Mac Catalyst. You may need to restrict the platforms for which this app extension should be embedded in the target editor.**

In the target editor **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content** I've selected only the macOS platform in my Safari Extension, but I get the same error, any clue?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've received an answer from Apple

> Embedding a Safari App Extension in a Catalyst app currently isn't
>   supported. If you could file a piece of Feedback in Feedback Assistant
>   that would be very helpful. Thanks!

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122485